# Wait for a key to be pressed inside loop

Tags: java, keyboard, awt, wait, keylistener

I have a java application and i want to wait for a key to be pressed to perform another action. Till now i have found:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
  if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT ) {
        //Right arrow key code
  }
}
```

but i want this to be inside a loop or something that waits until the key matches.

Please help.

**UPDATE:**

I want the program to be waiting until the key is pressed and when it is pressed i want to trigger another action. For example:

```
public void something(){
  //do something
  wait until a key is pressed
  if( key pressed is a arrow key){
    something();
  }else{
    wait for the key to be pressed
  }
}

public void dootherthing(){
 //do other thing
}
```

I am working in swing and i don't want the GUI to be irresponsible. i.e. when i call the dootherthing by click of a button. It should do it and the waiting should be over.

Comment: Why do you want it to be in a loop?

Comment: You can't wait in a loop within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  Doing so will prevent from processing new events, meaning you will never leave your loop...perhaps you should share what it is you are trying to do and we might be able to help you find a solution

Comment: You might also want to elaborate on what framework...AWT/Swing/JavaFX cause your just generating random answers at the moment...

Comment: You may also like to check out [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which will allow you to register a `Action` callback when a key stroke occurs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swing (and most GUIs) are event driven environments.  That is, something happens, you react to it.

Having a loop waiting for some kind of action is kind of counter intuitive (IMHO).

Generally speaking, you should avoid `KeyListener`s if you can.  They have issues with key focus.  The [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) API has ways to over come this limitation.

It allows you to register a `KeyStroke` against an `Action` and allows your program to sit back and wait till something happens...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class KeyBindings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new KeyBindings();
    }

    public KeyBindings() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            add(new KeyPane(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), gbc);

            gbc.gridy = 2;
            add(new KeyPane(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            add(new KeyPane(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 2;
            add(new KeyPane(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), gbc);

        }
    }

    public class KeyPane extends JPanel {

        public KeyPane(int keyCode, int modifier) {

            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));

            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, modifier, false), "keyPressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, modifier, true), "keyReleased");

            am.put("keyPressed", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    setBackground(Color.RED);
                }
            });

            am.put("keyReleased", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Panel.background"));
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(20, 20);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice to have been of use :D

Answer (score 0):

You can write a key listener

I found a Java tutorial that includes a Java WebStart sample and the source code. Looks like the winner is **KeyEvent.getKeyLocation()**

```
KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD
KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_LEFT
KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT
KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD
KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN
```

References:
[How to tell which SHIFT key was pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991765/how-to-tell-which-shift-key-was-pressed?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

keyPressed method will always be invoked whenever a key is pressed then why do you need it to be inside a loop?
From description it seems you are developing a typing game if it is so you can use Timeline class in JavaFX.

I have developed a very [simple typing game](https://github.com/mgosemath/simpletypinggame) in JavaFX have a look at it (code not properly organized).