# Press left shift using Robot class

Tags: java

```
Robot r=new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_LEFT);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_LEFT);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
```

I just tried to create virtual keyboard exactly equal to real one but I can't define left and right. I used the above code it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991765/how-to-tell-which-shift-key-was-pressed

Comment: The above link give the location of pressed button.But I need to press that button.Check my code I just used that method it doesn't works...

Answer (score 0):

I think that `r.keyPress(KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_LEFT);` does nothing as that constant refers to more than just the shift key and therefore cannot be "pressed".

Also the javadoc for [Robot.keyPress(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#keyPress(int)) states:

> Key codes that have more than one physical key associated with them
>   (e.g. KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT could mean either the left or right shift key)
>   will map to the left key.

Therefore I don't think it is possible to do what you are hoping using the Robot class. You might want to search for a different library if you require this functionality.